# laravel filament implementing dark mode does not work

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

I turned it to true but it doesn't work also when i change another thing also doesn't work like:

```
'sidebar' => [
            'is_collapsible_on_desktop' => true,
            'groups' => [
                'are_collapsible' => true,
            ],
            'width' => null,
            'collapsed_width' => null,
        ],
    ],
```

| header 1 | header 2 |
| --- | --- |
| cell 1 | cell 2 |
| cell 3 | cell 4 |

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who is coming across this post when searching for a solution, why dark mode does not work in Filament v2:

In my case, the issue was that in the "localStorage" the value for "theme" was already set to "system". You can check by running the following in your browser's console:

```js
localStorage.getItem('theme');
```

If that returns "system", you can resolve the issue by clearing the local storage:

1. Open the Google Chrome Console by pressing **F12** key.
2. Select **"Application"** in the console's top menu.
3. Select **"Local Storage"** in the console's left menu.
4. Right-click your site and click **"clear"** to delete the local storage.